# seem to have lost git commits in log, reflog still shows commits

Tags: git

I have a git project which is only local, and only has a master branch. Yesterday I made a number of commits. Today I made one commit. The commit look fine -- it was a diff on existing files and some new files.

However, when I look at my master branch in gitx, it only shows today's commit, and makes it look like I committed all files from scratch with this one commit.

Git log shows the same thing, but git reflog shows all my previous commits:

```
$ git log
 commit bd7d6af7f916706c5df6d57bed883d2c2d81f60f
 Author: Sam Fen
 Date:   Wed Jun 20 12:00:38 2012 -0400

  Add Genotype class, update naming

$ git reflog
 bd7d6af HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from master to master
 bd7d6af HEAD@{1}: commit: Add Genotype class, update naming
 bf0d3dd HEAD@{2}: commit: Add start to genetics manipulation library
 2335bf2 HEAD@{3}: commit: Convert to CoffeeScript
 4c26713 HEAD@{4}: commit: Initial commit with basic structure, trivial Jasmine t
```

The reflog shows what seems to be a weird double commit with the same hash (bd7d6af) for the last one, but I think that's just because after I saw the empty history in gitx, I went back to the command line and typed 'git checkout master' just to make sure I was on master (I was).

Any thoughts as to what might have happened, and how I can recover my history?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like bd7d6af thinks it is an initial commit

You can try `git reset bf0d3dd; git add -A; git commit` and see if you get a proper commit.

Comment: Yup, that seems to have fixed in. Any notion as to what might have caused it?

Comment: Sounds like something that might have happened if your refs/heads/master file was missing when you made your last commit; no idea how that could've happened though.

Answer (score 0):

If `bf0d3dd` is the last commit you made yesterday, you could:

```
git checkout master
git rebase --onto bf0d3dd master
```

This would take your current commit and rewrite it so that `bf0d3dd` is its parent, effectively re-attaching your master branch to history.

Not sure how it got into this state - there are a couple different ways it could, but we'd have to know more of the exact set of events you've been through.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same thing, and it happened like this:

- all the repository files are on a remote drive, like nfs, in a cloud and I guess this is a key point here.
- the internet cut off in the middle of the last commit being committed and some sort of unusual error popped up, didn't copy the exact notice.

as a result the only commit left is the last one and the rest disappeared. they are still in the reflog though